# Firefox "Open Containing Folder" launches Filelight instead of file manager. How to fix?

Tags: firefox, download-manager

I somehow changed which app is triggered by the "Open Containing Folder" option on downloaded files (as viewed in the download manager), so it now launches the Filelight disk-space-distribution viewer instead of my default file manager (Caja). This is not exactly useful.

How do I fix this? Where exactly is the setting for this app association?

I've tried following the advice from [this question](https://superuser.com/a/454579/40105) about removing Filelight to force Firefox to ask which app to use -- but now it just tries to open files with Audacious (an audio editor)! Re-installing Filelight reverts Firefox to using that again, but I didn't get the "open with" dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix:

```
xdg-mime default caja.desktop inode/directory
```

Comment: Well I did that, but I still got Filelight. So I restarted Firefox, and see that the "↓" toolbar button has disappeared (and can't be found under "Customize", either). So I tried via the menu "Tools->Downloads" ... and still got Filelight. Too bad.